# Assistance with FORM-SUBMIT & "?" removal from URL

Tags: php, javascript, html, form-submit

I was wondering how one would go about sending whatever the user types in text box; to the end of the `<form action=`. If one does not have access to the websites code source, how would one go about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link {color:#687BC6;}
        a:visited {color:#0F0;}
        a:hover {color:#000;}
        a:active {color:#0A0;}
    </style>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="get" action="http://www.blah.com/right-now/" target="_blank">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td>ZC:</td>
        <td><input name="fld-zip" type="text" maxlength="7" size="15"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name=Submit value="Submit this"></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pretty much asking how you can add ***what you put in text box*** to the end of URL ***/???*** when you click the submit button.

So it shows:
Textbox - "11722"
URL = http://www.blah.com/right-now/11722

Is there a way to do this via css/html/php/js?
Every time I click the SUBMIT button, it just adds a '?' at the end and it gets cut off.

Comment: use POST if urlencoding is a concern, otherwise urldecode()

Comment: u cant have a value with `&` character replace it with something

Comment: @Dagon, Can you break it down a little more?

Comment: @RPM, i'm trying to remove the '?' that shows up at the end of the URL. It keeps showing upon the Submission. I typed it wrong above. I didn't mean the '&' sign. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,m just giving it a try...i dunno whether it'll work or not.. do one thing,use two files..one to get the zip code..

=>in file 1,use a form.. after submitting,send the zip code to a dummy file(second file) i.e.,action="dummy.php"

=>in dummy file assign the zip code to a variable '$a'

```
$a=$_GET['zip'];
```

now use javascript

```
<script>
function a()
{
newwindow=open("http://www.blah.com/rightnow/'$a'",window,"height=900,width=1100");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmmm, i'll give it a try. Never thought of that. Tossed it around before, but I couldn't properly obtain user(s) IP to convert to .geolocation. But I think you mean just send it to mysite.com/dummy.php?
And in that case: Have dummy.php take in the new data, and re-direct to the function a?'

Comment: yes..that can be a simple onload function..or you can also use windows.location.href="./rightnow/'$a'" in the dummy file

Comment: I think I did it wrong. Do you think you can give example? I know you did above, but i'm not too savy with onload

Comment: <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function display()
  {
  window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload=display()>

 </body>
</html>

Comment: ohhhhhh. I see what you mean

EDIT*

I feel like such a noob. 
Do you think I can link you to a sub site, and you can help me? Unless there's a chat on SO?

Comment: i didn't get u...elaborate a bit more

Comment: Can we chat somewhere? To avoid extended discussions in comments? I don't have enough Rep to chat on StackOverflow. So I was wondering if you wanted to help me thoroughly? I feel like a noob because something soooo simple, is difficult for me right now. Maybe cuz it's AM here.

Comment: okay bro...not a problem...my gmail id:bhuvan.kai@gmail.com...ping me..but i'm in office and its about time to leave...it is 6.30 pm here..so i'll help u tomorrow

Comment: Ok, sounds good to me. I greatly appreciate this. Thank-you a ton! I just sent you email. Subject is: StackOverflows Antarctican

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this at the top of the page.

```
<?php
if (!(empty($_GET['fld-zip']))){ //check if the var is empty
$url = "http://www.blah.com/right-now/"; 
$page = $_GET['fld-zip'];
header("location:$url . $page"); //if its all good then redirect to the correct page
}
?>
```

This could probably be done a bunch of different ways but should work.

The ? is there because the form is submitted using get it wont go away and shouldnt. Do some reading on GET and POST in HTML forms.

Comment: `If one does not have access to the websites code source` He does not have access to the destination PHP

Comment: totally missed that. I guess you could inject some javascript then but I would question what he is trying to do if he doesnt have access to the source.

Comment: Well, on a site i'm currently assisting in, I was asked to help with a way to get LOCAL WEATHER. And well, I was going to use weather.com's Weather Lookup feature. So, at the end of the URL is where the city,state, and/or zip goes. So, I was trying to create a Form and have the user(s) type their c/s/z in the box, and upon submitting it, they will be redirected to the weather.com site. I went out of my way to give thanx and credit to them as well.

I put 'blah.com' because I didn't know if I was allowed to request this type of thing. I self-taught myself all I know about PCs, so I missed alot

Answer (score 0):

Add a script like this

```
function formSubmit(){
   document.getElementById('frm1').setAttribute('action', "http://www.google.com/right-now/" +   document.form1["fld-zip"].value)
   document.form1["fld-zip"].value = '';
   return true;
}
```

then add `onsubmit` event to your form

```
<form id="frm1" name="form1" method="get" action="http://www.blah.com/right-now/" target="_blank" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/FtRKp/4/

Comment: http://www.blah.com/right-now/?fld-zip=11722&Submit=Submit+this

^^^ That is how the link shows. I need it to be: http://www.blah.com/right-now/11722

If that is possible at all. And THANK-YOU ALL for taking your time to help me.

Comment: @TheAntarctican I have updated my answer with example, please read

Answer (score 0):

if you use GET, the link should look something like "http://www.blah.com/right-now?variable1=11722&variable2=11733. The question mark is at the beginning of the variables. How does it get cut off?

If you're using http://www.blah.com/right-now/ as the action, make sure that http://www.blah.com/right-now/index.php has the logic.

Comment: Should I be using GET at all?

is there another way around this?
I simply want the user to put in their 1-7digit zip, and upon clicking the submit button, it takes you to www.blah.com/right-now/(zip goes here).
Instead, all attempts have either left in a non-existing page due to the ?(all else) or to mysite.com/right-now/(zip goes here).

Answer (score 0):

As your basically wanting to just open a new window with the value of what's entered in the text box concatenated on to a url;
Change your form slightly, use a button instead of a submit, and with the use of jquery(cleaner imo) and a simple js function to put it altogether & trigger it from the forms `onClick="doForm()"`.

```
<script>
function doForm(){
   var param = $("#fld-zip").val();
   window.open ("http://www.blah.com/right-now/" + param,"openwindow");
}
</script>

<form name="form1" method="get" action="" target="_blank">
  ZC:<input name="fld-zip" id="fld-zip" type="text" maxlength="7" size="15">
     <input type="button" name="Submit" onClick="doForm()" value="Submit this">
</form>
```

Comment: If OP's website does not use jQuery anywhere else, using jQuery just to get an input field's value is overkill. Instead of `$("#fld-zip").val()`, `document.getElementById("fld-zip").value` should suffice.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: Well, I tried, but blah.com is the site I need to open in a new window. But what it's doing is: http://mysite.com/local-weather.php?fld-zip=11722

It brings the user to my page, but simply adds the: ?fld.zip=11722

Comment: @Phil, do you think you can help a little more? I got confused with what everyone wrote